# We are given a graph $K_6$. How many pairwise non-isomorphic graphs can we get if we delete 3 edges?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am looking for help with the question above. Actually have no idea what the answer is and especially how to prove the answer. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subgraphs $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic iff their complements $K_6 \setminus G$ and $K_6 \setminus H$ are isomorphic.  Now it is a matter of counting graphs with $6$ nodes and $3$ edges.  The three edges can be in three different components, yielding $1$ subgraph $K_2 \cup K_2 \cup K_2$.  The three edges can be in two different components, yielding the union of a path of length $2$ and $K_2$.  The three edges can be in one component in $3$ different ways: a path of length $3$, a triangle $K_3$, or a star $K_{1,3}$.  The total count is therefore $1+1+3=5$.

Comment: +1 since it is quickly obtained from the graph complements

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 non-isomorphic graphs with $6$ vertices and $12$ edges with adjacency list form as follows.

```
1: 1[4 5 6] 2[4 5 6] 3[4 5 6] 4[1 2 3 5 6] 5[1 2 3 4 6] 6[1 2 3 4 5]
2: 1[3 4 5 6] 2[4 5 6] 3[1 5 6] 4[1 2 5 6] 5[1 2 3 4 6] 6[1 2 3 4 5]
3: 1[3 4 5 6] 2[5 6] 3[1 4 5 6] 4[1 3 5 6] 5[1 2 3 4 6] 6[1 2 3 4 5]
4: 1[3 4 5 6] 2[3 4 5 6] 3[1 2 5 6] 4[1 2 6] 5[1 2 3 6] 6[1 2 3 4 5]
5: 1[3 4 5 6] 2[3 4 5 6] 3[1 2 5 6] 4[1 2 5 6] 5[1 2 3 4] 6[1 2 3 4]
```

[image]
I recommend [nauty on the web](http://combos.org/nauty) for situations where graphs have few vertices or  edges. Of course, the problem you are considering can be handled by hand.

**Edits:**   Thanks RobPratt for informing me that my original answer was wrong.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake setting.

Comment: Your recommended nauty search returns $5$, not $9$.  Did you maybe search for minimum of $12$ edges?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the reminder.